# Problems with pins for interruption and motor DC - Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino, interrupt, encoder

I am working in a project which requires me to read the velocity of a DC motor with a quadrature encoder. I am using the Arduino UNO board and for some weird reason the motor just works if it is connected to the pins 2 and 3. However this pins are reserved for the interruption (where I intended to connect the encoder). How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: And the schematic...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the arduino can provide enough current, you should be able to run the motor from any output pin, check out [this diagram](http://foros.giltesa.com/otros/arduino/fc/docs/pinout/uno.jpg) for reference. You should also make sure you have the necessary protection circuits in place. This is a good starting point: https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/licensedGeek/controlling-a-dc-motor-from-an-arduino-101-board-f4954b